# Inverse of function $f(x)=x^3+3x+1$

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

If $f:R \to R, f(x)=x^3+3x+1$ then find the inverse of $f(x)$.

$f(x)$ is one to one (as it is increasing function for $x \in R$) and onto as well (Range is same as co-domain) but I don't know how to find inverse here as I am not able to write $x$ as a function of y.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Find *explicit* inverse o proving *existence* of inverse?

Comment: In this case Cardano's method will work, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method

Comment: Write $y=f(x)$ to get a cubic equation in $x$. Then just solve it for $x$ and you will get an expression involving $y$ as $y$ appears in the coefficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the inverse of $f(x) = x^3 + x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770055/finding-the-inverse-of-fx-x3-x)

Answer (score 1):

For many — in fact, I would argue for *most* — purposes, the best expression for the inverse is

> $g$ is the inverse of $f$

or maybe

> $g(x) = a$ where $a$ is the unique value satisfying $f(a) = x$

and work with it in those terms. For example, do you want the derivative of $g$? The best way to compute it is with implicit differentiation:

$$f(g(x)) = x \implies g'(x) f'(g(x)) = 1 \implies g'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(g(x))} $$

Even if you had an algebraic formula for $g$, you would probably *strongly* prefer to compute the derivative in this fashion.

Another example: want the asymptotic behavior of $g(x)$ as $x \to \infty$? Use the behavior of $f$ and a change of variable:

$$ 1 = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^3} = \lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{f(g(y))}{g(y)^3} = \lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y}{g(y)^3}  $$

from which we conclude

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{x^{1/3}} = 1 $$

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get how this information would help me in finding in inverse of concerned function.

Comment: @Akira: The inverse is trivial to find: it's simply $f^{-1}$. The point of my post is an attempt to disabuse you of the notion that $f^{-1}$ is not an adequate formula for whatever purpose you have for the inverse.

Comment: In total agreement with this answer, I would say that although the existence of the Cardano formula is of great *theoretical* interest, it’s unlikely that any *understanding* would be gained by its use, for instance in further computations. On the other hand, dealing with $f^{-1}$ as an increasing function, continuous and even infinitely differentiable, will best be done simply by referring to it in the way that the answerer here recommends.

Answer (score 0):

write $x^3 + 3x + 1 = a,$ so $x^3 + 3x + (1-a) = 0.$ There is exactly one real solution $x.$ Therefore Cardano's method will allow us to find this $x$ explicitly with real-valued square roots and cube roots. That is, we avoid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis regardless of the value of $a.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method

[image]